# Minikube. How to allow access to local mySQL database from container

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, localhost, minikube

I'm trying to access to local MySQL database from minikube container. My minikube works on Windows 10 with hyper-v driver. I found a few solutions (creating host-only network from VirtualBox) but nothing for hyper-v. Can somebody assist me how can I connect to localhost mysql server from minikube hyper-v?

Comment: See "docker volume".

Answer (score 4):

Minikube v1.10 added a hostname to the cluster DNS that allows pods to connect to the host. Have your pods use this DNS entry to access the host IP. At this time, the DNS hostname is `host.minikube.internal`

See [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and then create an `Endpoint`  with the IP of your MySQL.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
---
# Because this service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoints
# object will not be created. You can manually map the service to
# your own specific endpoints:
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: "23.99.34.75"
    ports:
      - port: 3306
```

Also you can check this question [Connect to local database from inside minikube cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952240/connect-to-local-database-from-inside-minikube-cluster).

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I get mySql IP? Is it my external IP?

Comment: I would deploy that MySQL inside a docker container so it would be easy to connect to.

Comment: It is like an option. I thought about this. But for me looks like an extra job.

Answer (score 0):

Get your host ip by `HOST_IP=$(minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'")`

According to K8s [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) apply:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-db
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP

---
kind: EndpointSlice
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-db-endpoint
  labels:
      kubernetes.io/service-name: mysql-db
addressType: IPv4
ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: ''
    appProtocol: http
    protocol: TCP
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - $HOST_IP
```